# How to add Id to all the rows of dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Hi my csv file structure is like

```
File-1

    id col1 col2
    a_1  sd    fd
       ds    emd
       sf    jhk

File-2

    id col1 col2
    b_2  sd    fd
       ds    emd
       sf    jhk
```

Now I want that when I load my csv file into the dataframe my id column for the all the rows of this file 1 should have value 1 and of file 2 value 2. So my datframe should look like-

```
    id  col1  col2
    a_1  sd    fd
    a_1  ds    emd
    a_1  sf    jhk
    b_2  sd    fd
    b_2  ds    emd
    b_2  sf    jhk
```

I want to do this so I can identify the rows by file id if I am reading multiple csv file.Please note that I dont want to add filename as id, I want to use the id column in the first row of file to extend to all the corresponding rows of file in the dataframe.

Comment: This post explain about adding the filename as id, I want to use the id column in the first row of file to extend to all the corresponding rows of file in the dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

if you are sure if its going to be in the first row.
Below is psudo code.

```
file1_id = df_file1.filter(id != None).select(col('id')).collect()[0]
```

and then use the above calculated id for the file as

```
df_file1.drop('id').withColumn('id',lit(file1_id))
```

Follow the same for the second dataframe df_file2
then do a union

```
df_file = df_file1.unionAll(df_file2)
```

Comment: I can have multiple files which I am reading from my hdfs directory, it will be difficult to create a separate dataframe for all of them.

Comment: Loop through the directory create df for each file and put it in an array. and you can still use the above code by traversing the array. This could help if you have fewer then 20 files in the directory. You can also remove the filter that i have put as the id will be in the first row

Comment: Agreed but I have more than 1k files in the directory and it wont make sense to create DF for them seperately.